# Twitter is not showing carousels of multiple messages sent at once

Tags: twitter, smooch

I have integrated my app with Twitter through Smooch. And i am sending multiple messages containing multiple actions of postback type. Twitter is just showing options for the last message though all the message texts are listed in the chat dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter doesn't have native support for carousels as a message type. The experience you see on Twitter is sort of Smooch's best effort at rendering the content. In the case of postback buttons, they fall back to a text-only implementation as "You can say: X, Y", and expect a user response to trigger it. The reason they only render for the last message in the series is because multiple carousel items could have the same text "X", so if the user were to reply with X, you wouldn't know which carousel item they are referring to.

Basically, sending carousels on Twitter is not fully supported, especially in the case of postback buttons. See https://docs.smooch.io/guide/channel-capabilities/ for capability support on different channels